# add string to end of line ansible

Tags: ansible, nagios

I want to create a role to do a dynamic update of my Nagios configuration when I create a new VM.

So to do that, i already created a role which add a host definition at the end of my servers.cfg Nagios file, it looks like :

```
- name: Add {{ Host_Name }} in /etc/naemon/conf.d/hosts/servers.cfg
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/naemon/conf.d/hosts/servers.cfg
    block: |
      define host {
        host_name                      {{ Host_Name }}
        alias                          {{ Host_Name }}.uem.lan
        address                        {{ Host_IP }}
        use                            modele_host,host-pnp
      }
    marker:   ""
    backup: yes
```

It works well.

So now I would like to be able to add my "`{{ Host_Name }}`" server directly at the end of lines of checks files.

Exemple : This is a check to monitore `/data` partition :

```
define service {
  service_description            /data partition
  host_name                      myserv1,myserv2,myserv3,myserv4,myserv5
  use                            srv-pnp,modele_service_disk_linux_snmp
  check_command                  check_snmp_storage!uem_snmp!/data$!90!95
}
```

And I would to add my "`{{ Host_Name }}`" like that :

```
define service {
  service_description            /data partition
  host_name                      myserv1,myserv2,myserv3,myserv4,myserv5,{{ Host_Name }}
  use                            srv-pnp,modele_service_disk_linux_snmp
  check_command                  check_snmp_storage!uem_snmp!/data$!90!95
}
```

Would anyone have a solution?

Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach will be different, but it should working with Nagios 3 and 4.

Just edit your first Ansible task a little bit:

```
- name: Add {{ Host_Name }} in /etc/naemon/conf.d/hosts/servers.cfg
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/naemon/conf.d/hosts/servers.cfg
    block: |
      define host {
        host_name                      {{ Host_Name }}
        alias                          {{ Host_Name }}.uem.lan
        address                        {{ Host_IP }}
        hostgroup_name                 anything
        use                            modele_host,host-pnp
      }
    marker:   ""
    backup: yes
```

Then replace your service definition with this:

```
define service {
  service_description            /data partition
  hostgroup_name                 anything
  use                            srv-pnp,modele_service_disk_linux_snmp
  check_command                  check_snmp_storage!uem_snmp!/data$!90!95
}
```

Everytime when you add new host via Ansible to *anything* hostgroup and restart/reload Nagios service you will monitor your `/data` partition without addition work.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try with the following:

```
- name: 'LINEINFILE'
  lineinfile:
    path: 'service.cfg'
    line: '{{item.line}}'
    regexp: '{{item.regexp}}'
    backrefs: True
  loop:
    - { line: '\1\2', regexp: '(\s*host_name.*),{{inventory_hostname}}(.*)' }
    - { line: '\1,{{inventory_hostname}}', regexp: '(\s*host_name.*)' }
```

Pretty ugly, but idempotent.